# JavaScript: Bold all table td entries which contain "*sometext*" on mouse-over

Tags: javascript, css

I have a `table` element on some page. It contains some table rows with cells, containing `href`s.

My target is: when I point mouse cursor over some `href` with text "sometext", all table hrefs that contain this "sometext" text to become with bold text. On mouse-out, all hrefs should go to normal state.

Thanks,
Venelin

Comment: Are you bound to plain JavaScript or can u use jQuery?

Comment: I prefer raw JS, but any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: If you can post some example HTML it would get you faster and more accurate answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery (which you said may be acceptable) it could be something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('td > a').hover(
       function() {
           $('td > a:contains("' + this.innerHTML + '")').css('font-weight', 'bold')
       },
       function() {
           $('td > a').css('font-weight', 'normal')
       }
   )
})
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/2ATc5/3/

When mouse enters anchor within TD - code looks for all anchors within TDs that have the same text and bolds them.

When mouse leaves the anchor - font-weight returns to normal.

Comment: Hello Yuriy, thanks for you answer. I just tried your approach by downloading jquery, add it to my page, add your code, but with no success. I really like short code approach but in this case I can't archive my target.

Comment: @VenelinSpiridonov Make sure you include reference to jQuery.JS into your page and also wrap the code into `document.ready()` - see my updated code above

Comment: Here is the result "[Error] TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'document.ready')
 global code"

Comment: My bad. It's supposed to be `$(document).ready( )`. Updated the code

Comment: Glad it was helpful :) Sorry about mistakes on the way. And now since you're using jQuery - life should become a whole lot easier for you for other issues and features.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/f82KA/14/

---

```
<table>
    <tr><td><a href="#">Android</a><a href="#">Applesometext</a><a href="#">Symbiansometext</a></td><td><a href="#">Android</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="#">Windows</a><a href="#">Symbiansometext</a><a href="#">Applesometext</a></td><td><a href="#">Windows</a></td></tr>
</table>
```

---

```
var p = /sometext/;
var s = document.querySelectorAll('td a');

function boldAll(b) {
    for(var i=0;i<s.length;i++) {
        if(b) {
            if(p.test(s[i].innerHTML)) {
                s[i].style.fontWeight = 'bold';
            }
        } else {
            s[i].style.fontWeight = 'normal';
        }
    }
}

function h(e) {
    if(p.test(e.target.innerHTML)) {
        boldAll(true);
    }
}

for(var i=0;i<s.length;i++) {
    s[i].addEventListener('mouseover',h);
    s[i].addEventListener('mouseout',function(e) {
        boldAll(false);
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi dude, thanks for you effort in this answer. I try to add this in my head section of page, but there were no change when pointing mouse over some href in cell. Sorry.

Comment: oh, I am afraid you didn't get the question. Try Yuriy Galanter link, it performs the needs, but I can't make it work for my page. And yes, I use <script></script> tags :).

Comment: @VenelinSpiridonov You Sir! Did you visit this link - http://jsfiddle.net/f82KA/4/ ?

Comment: Yes mate. Please check my question again. I need more than one href in table cell and when one href in table cell is mouse pointed, all hrefs in table with same text in it must became bold. :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43448/discussion-between-venelin-spiridonov-and-gles)

Answer (score 0):

Best method would be to set class to any cell with the specific text while making the HTML.
If it's impossible, You can use simple script to do so on load:

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
 <html>
   <head>
     <title> Bla! </title>
     <style type='text/css'>
        td.boldOn:hover { font-weight:bold; color:red; }
     </style>
     <script type='text/javascript'>
        function Init() {
            var obj = document.getElementById('tblId');
            for (var i =0, row; row=obj.rows[i]; i++) {
                for (var j=0, cell; cell= row.cells[j]; j++) {
                    if( cell.innerHTML.indexOf('ing') != -1) {
                        cell.className = 'boldOn';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
     </script>
   </head>
   <body onload='Init();'>
        <table id='tblId' border='1'>
            <tr>
                <td> not bold </td>
                <td> bolding </td>
                <td> not bold </td>
                <td> bolding </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> not bold </td>
                <td> bolding </td>
                <td> not bold </td>
                <td> bolding </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
   </body>
 </html>
```

If you can do it ahead - then simply to the 'bolding' td's add :

```
<td class='boldOn'> bolding </td>
```

and all the js is useless.

Comment: Kind of valuable loop. How can I extend it to loop all hrefs in cell and check their contains.